# How to use Crystal Report viewer in ASP.net MVC without using .aspx?

Tags: crystal-reports, aspx-user-control

my Question is how to use Crystal Report Viewer in ASP MVC without using ASPX Control. currently i'm using crystal report viewer with using ASPx but Report design and formatting is not alignment properly but when i export to PDF or other Format is work Fine but not showing properly in viewer. what can i do ?enter image description here

view in PDF

[image]

[image]

Comment: As described in the following tutorial, you can user Crystal Report in ASP.NET MVC :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-crystal-report-with-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: @BabakFakhriloo The OP is asking how to use the report viewer CONTROL to view a report, not how to run a report and output it as a PDF.